# Hough transform: how to actually detect shapes?

Tags: python, hough-transform

I have a little project where I'm trying to detect traffic signs in an image, using Python.
I have implemented the equivalent of `cv.HoughLines` to detect lines in an image, using an accumulator.
However, let's say I want to detect a shape. I have detected the lines. But how can I know where is the shape? Whether it is a triangle or a square... (traffic sign)
Also, I must keep using Hough transform, and implement it myself...

I have tried finding intersections to detect triangles. However, sometimes I get too much points, and I would like to find the bounds of the geometrical shape.

```
def find_intersections(lines):
    intersections = []

    for i in range(len(lines)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(lines)):
            m1, p1, _, _, _, _ = lines[i]
            m2, p2, _, _, _, _ = lines[j]

            if m1 != m2:
                x = (p2 - p1) / (m1 - m2)
                y = m1 * x + p1
                intersections.append((x, y))

    return intersections
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to find shapes with HoughLines greatly depends on the quality of lines your implementation provides. Here are few things I have done in the past when working on similar task. I assume you have done some image pre-processing like converting to greyscale or use only one color channel, using Canny edges with parameters tuned for your use-case etc. I highly recommend tuning the Canny edge detector parameters first before you call your implementation of `cv2.HoughLines`. Pre-processing goes a LONG way.

**Things to try in your implementation of HoughLines:**

- Tune the size of bins.
- Tune the voting scheme. If you are getting too many lines after your implementation, you may have to increase the threshold of the peaks (so you take only the long enough lines).

**Things to try once you have the candidate lines from HoughLines:**

- Find the mean (x,y) coordinate of lines that are very close -- There may be noisy edges that were not suppressed during edge detection, some of which your algorithm might have picked as individual lines. If it's hard to suppress those edges by tuning your edge detector, the alternative is to squash them into a single line by taking the mean of end coordinates (or other methods) of those noisy lines.
- If you have an estimated number of pixels that will make up the sign (area of the sign), use that as a heuristic.

Visualize at each step, use a trackbar to help with manual tuning of all parameters. You can learn more about trackbar implementation [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d6a/tutorial_trackbar.html).

Comment: Yes, I use canny edge detection and have a grayscale filter. I will try the pre-processing advice, but the area is "dynamic" and I don't see how the mean coordinate of lines can help with actually finding the bounds of a shape?

Comment: @sky1099 - My bad. I added more details on what I meant by  finding the mean (x,y) coordinates of lines that are very close.